# Azure maps pin color is wrong

Tags: azure-maps

Using Azure.Maps.Rendering I am setting the pin and label colors. The label color works fine. But the pin color, while it does change based on the setting, does not match the setting. For example, for the following code:

```
var pushpinSet = new ImagePushpinStyle(new List<PushpinPosition>() { position })
{
    PushpinScaleRatio = 0.8, //1.2,
    PushpinColor = Color.Red,
    LabelColor = Color.Green,
    LabelScaleRatio = 10 //18
};
```

I get the map:

[image]

That's not red. Any idea how to get this to work?

Comment: Do other pin colors exhibit this behavior? Maybe https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/38100 ?

Comment: @ceejayoz That's it - known bug. If you make your comment an answer, happy to accept it. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This unfortunately appears to be [a known bug](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/38100) in the SDK at this time.

> Currently, in azure-sdk-for-net/sdk/maps/Azure.Maps.Rendering/src/Models/ImagePushpinStyle.cs, the pushpin color information is extracted, but unfortunately the alpha value is also used for the blue component, instead of the blue value...